# Flatten JSON based on an attribute - python

Tags: python, arrays, json, serialization, json-deserialization

I have a json array like this:

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'values': [
            {
                'cat_key': 'ck1'
            },
            {
                'cat_key': 'ck2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'values': [
            {
                'cat_key': ck3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to flatten this array on the field `values` such that:

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'cat_key': 'ck1'
    },
    {
        'id': 1,
        'cat_key': 'ck2'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'cat_key': 'ck3'
    }
]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = json.loads(json_array)
new_obj = [] 
for d in obj:
    if d.get('values'):
        for value in d['values']:
            new_obj.append(dict(id=d['id'],cat_key=value['cat_key']))
new_json = json.dumps(new_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not technically valid, but assuming it is and that is iterable as a `list`:

```
out = []
for d in your_json:
    for v in d.get('values', []):
        out.append({'id': d['id'], 'cat_key': v['cat_key']})
print json.dumps(out)
```

Result:

```
[{"id": 1, "cat_key": "ck1"}, {"id": 1, "cat_key": "ck2"}, {"id": 2, "cat_key": "ck3"}]
```